# Most computationally efficient way to create new rows in in pandas dataframe using function operation on each rows column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a dataframe where two columns contain ints

```
A  B 
3  3
4  6
6  4
7  4
```

And I want to create a function that creates a new row from existing columns

```
def new_rows(row):
    for idx in range (row['A']):
        c = idx*row['B']
        row['C'] = c
        return row
```

So the resulting dataframe would be

```
A.  B.   C 
3.  3.   0
3.  3.   3
3.  3.   6
4.  6    0
4.  6    6
4.  6    12
4.  6    18
6  4.    0
...
...
...
```

As far as I can tell, pandas map and apply can be used to create new columns, but not additional rows

The best solution I can think of us using pandas iterrows applying the operations during the iterations, saving all the values to a list of dictionaries, and then creating a pandas dataframe of that list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this in a vectorized way , using [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) on df.A and `groupby.cumcount` to generate the range and multiply with B:

```
def myf(data):
    a = data.loc[data.index.repeat(df['A'])]
    a['C'] = a.groupby("A").cumcount()*data['B']
    return a.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(myf(df))


    A  B   C
0   3  3   0
1   3  3   3
2   3  3   6
3   4  6   0
4   4  6   6
5   4  6  12
6   4  6  18
7   6  4   0
8   6  4   4
9   6  4   8
10  6  4  12
11  6  4  16
12  6  4  20
13  7  4   0
14  7  4   4
15  7  4   8
16  7  4  12
17  7  4  16
18  7  4  20
19  7  4  24
​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension with `explode`:

```
print (df.assign(C=[np.arange(x)*y for x, y in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]).explode("C"))

   A  B   C
0  3  3   0
0  3  3   3
0  3  3   6
1  4  6   0
1  4  6   6
1  4  6  12
1  4  6  18
2  6  4   0
2  6  4   4
2  6  4   8
2  6  4  12
2  6  4  16
2  6  4  20
3  7  4   0
3  7  4   4
3  7  4   8
3  7  4  12
3  7  4  16
3  7  4  20
3  7  4  24
```